# Good Windows Usenet reader which can get post count for all groups?

Tags: usenet, newsreader

I have a need for a specific Windows Usenet reader which can list the post count for all the groups. Newsbin, a reader can do this but every time I try to read a message I get an error message which states it can't decode the body. I know my news server is fine because I can read messages using other readers.

Anyone knows other readers which can list post counts for all the groups. The count is provided by the news server.

Comment: Related question: http://superuser.com/questions/12823/looking-for-good-newsreader-program

Answer (score 3):

**[Forté Agent](http://www.forteinc.com/agent/index.php)** is quite old-looking but has a lot of features, including listing post counts. I've been using it for ages!

[image]

Comment: How do you get the post counts?

Comment: I added a screenshot. Or I don't understand what you mean with "post counts".

Comment: forte - the only real reader nowadays. +1

Comment: the post count for all Usenet groups. Not just the ones you're subscribed to

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Thunderbird](http://www.mozillamessaging.com/thunderbird/)? I used it throughout university for newsgroups with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [Grabit](http://www.shemes.com/) can do this:

> GrabIt, one of the easiest Usenet content downloaders in the world.
>   With GrabIt you can search and download any content on USENET news
>   servers, without downloading gigabytes of headers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use [XanaNews](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/xananews.htm), which lists the number of posts to any group I'm subscribed too.

Updated binaries are [available here](http://xananews.techtips.com.br/).

Answer (score 0):

Been using Xnews for over 10 year. Does exactly what you want - load header count for all subscribed groups, or even all groups if you so choose.

[link text](http://download.cnet.com/Xnews/3000-2164_4-10026377.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've used Gravity (now SuperGravity) and was happy with it.  You can read more about it [here](http://lightning.prohosting.com/~tbates/gravity/super.html).

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Omea Reader](http://www.jetbrains.com/omea/reader/) from JetBrains for a couple of years.  I like all the different views you can switch between, like Today, Yesterday, This week, etc.  Search is quite good and the ability to switch between flat results and conversations.  I only use it for newsgroups.

If you are looking for something with Outlook integration they also have Omea Pro.  I have not used that one, but it looks similar, just more features.

Both are free now.  But it looks like they have NOT updated them in the last couple of years.  Still, solid newsreader and worth the look.